# Budgie DE on Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspbian-buster, desktop

I've tried to install the budgie desktop on my raspberry pi 4 for almost a week now. people on discord told me to run a set of commands that allegedly worked for them. However, I have a fresh raspbian install, but I cannot get it to work. I was told to run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install task-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get install budgie-desktop slick-greeter gnome-terminal
```

running the first command gives me a dkpg error; basically

```
dkpg: error unpacking archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-software_3.30.6-5_armhf.deb (—unpack)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dkpg returned a error code (1)
```

So I run apt clean and I try again but no dice.

is there a fix for this? should I run something else?

Comment: Ah, let me see. I have been playing with Rpi for about 5 hobbyist years. And from time to time I tried to install interesting packages and failed, sometime wasting long hours. I learned many lessons, including the following: (1) Packages that can be installed in one Raspbian version might not work for the next upgrade. (2) Even with the exact OS version and release, there might be software driver conflicts and hardware conflicts, especially Rpi3 to Rpi4.

Comment: From time to time, I read tutorials and instructables claiming that they can do things very impressive, but they won't tell you which OS version they are using. And sometimes even they know new OS version not long work, they won't tell you, for some reasons.

Comment: So I usually do not try be the first user, and I need to know the level of linux knowledge or prerequisites and see if I can handle the version to version teething problems.

Comment: And are you using the ubunto version, which might not be compatible to Rpi4B buster release 2020feb05.

Comment: no im using raspbian buster 2020-2-5 version

Comment: I see.  I installed buster release 2020feb05 a couple of days ago. Just now I used GUI destop Add/Remove Softare option to search for keyword "budgie" and found some 30 packages I can install. Usually I started with the basic config, ignoring fancy things or app etc. I usually try this GUI search and install first, for two reasons: (1) I found that if the package is too complicated, I don't have the prerequisite linux skill to check the dependencies and pip the missing packages,

Comment: (1)  GUI search and install is very newbie friendly, handling the dependency problems transparently.  So in some cases, even the experience linux CLI users could not find the missing dependent libraries to install, GUI Add/Remove Software is my friend

Comment: . (2) Another tricky thing also disturbed the ninjas, not to mention me newbie, is that, if you used the wrong pip3 or your default pip2, you will make a big mess and you can't go back. My prevention and not cure is too prepare a couple of SD cards, and on any installation, I won't try to pip, curl, nmp etc etc making the mess bigger, I just use a fresh sd card. But as I said earlier, after too many installation failures, I have become humble, and wait for the brave guys to try first, and me follow later..

Comment: @lockheedsilverman Check [this link](https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/tutorial-installing-ubuntu-budgie-on-a-raspberry-pi/1787) out.

Comment: @tlfong01 yeah, you are right. thats always been frustrating for me as well.

Comment: @lockheed silverman, yes I agree in real life, many things, including Rpi, are frustrating, but improving. I sometimes take it easy, often giving up, but determined to wait and see, googled more, and come back when the time comes (I did gave Rpi One, then came back to Rpi Two a yr later). I remember that the first couple of times I tried to install linux packages in my Rpi One days, it often took me more that 3 hours struggling, before giving up.  But then I gradually learn more linux tricks, and know if I am hitting a wall, so I give up as soon as I guess it is the right time to do,. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**budgie-desktop** is available from the default Raspbian repository. This means it should be installable without worrying about dependencies about other needed packages. This is why we use the package manager environment (apt, apt-get, dpkg etc.). If you look at the description of the package you will find:

```
rpi ~$ apt show budgie-desktop
--- snip ---
This package installs the minimal GNOME based package-set together with
the key budgie-desktop packages to produce a working desktop
environment.
```

So just install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install budgie-desktop
```

and it should do. If you use a Raspbian image with the default desktop then it will install **budgie-desktop** in addition to it, I think. If you like to save resources then you can try to install budgie-desktop on **Raspbian Lite** so you only have this one desktop.

Comment: i tried it. it installs some things, however when i run ‘sudo update-alternatives —config x-session-manager, there are no budgie options as far as i can tell, just defaults

Comment: @lockheedsilverman What are "things"? Are there error messages? Does the setup failed? Have you had a look at the logging? You should find something at `/usr/share/doc/budgie` or similar. Have you had a look at it?